# How can I expose FusionAuth on Ubuntu + Apache to connect from browser?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, fusionauth

I have been digging into the FusionAuthdocumentation and I can't find the way to do it.

I am running Ubuntu 22 + Apache + MySQL. I have pointed *fusionauth.my-domain.com* to such server.

I just installed the DEB package and I want to configure it, but I cannot find the way to give access to it from my browser on a "production" environment.

The only reference I found was for development mode: https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/developer-guide/exposing-instance

Can you throw some light?
What should I do to access to *fusionauth.my-domain.com:9011* to do the installation?

Thanks,
Javi

**-- EDIT --**

On the Apache [conf files](https://github.com/FusionAuth/fusionauth-contrib/blob/master/Reverse%20Proxy%20Configurations/apache/apache.ssl.conf), it only mentiones how one tenant or application can be used:

```
# Change the following:
# ab613909-571b-457c-a89e-336764f545d7 -> to the client_id of your application
# 92e5c59d-4a54-499d-944f-70a06a4881a2 -> to the tenant ID of your tenant
```

How can the rewrite rules be modified to handle two application IDs?
Should I "copy-paste"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options.

Option 1:

You can expose the FusionAuth server directly to the internet. This means allowing traffic to port 9011 (which is what FusionAuth listens on). How to do so depends on your hosting provider, so I'd ask them how to expose a service running on a non-standard port to the internet. This has the downside of running HTTP, not HTTPS, but is useful for testing functionality.

You can terminate TLS at FusionAuth, but you need to then install SSL certificates, which is beyond the scope of this answer. Read up on that option here: https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/reference/configuration by searching for "HTTPS server".

Option 2:

You can also run a proxy such as apache httpd or nginx. You'll have to configure the proxy to forward connections to FusionAuth.

This is how you probably want to run FusionAuth in a production setting. Here's [documentation about proxy configuration](https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/admin-guide/proxy-setup), and [sample proxy configs contributed by the community](https://github.com/FusionAuth/fusionauth-contrib/tree/master/Reverse%20Proxy%20Configurations).

Comment: that is awesome! Thanks for referring to the samples!